# Vim magic closing bracket

Tags: vim

It would be great in vim if I could type `]` (or some other character, maybe `<C-]>`) and have it automatically insert whichever bracket properly closes the opening bracket.  Eg. if I have this in my buffer:

```
object(function(x) { x+[1,2,3
```

And I press `]]]`, the characters `]})` would be inserted.  How might one accomplish this this?

Comment: Have you tried [autoclose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) ?

Comment: @khachik - `autoclose` closes the brackets immediately and it's rather annoying, at least for me.

Comment: When I was first taught programming, many haircuts ago, I was told to close my brackets as soon as I opened them. It's stuck with me since then and works in any editor :-)

Comment: I've expanded nperson325681's answer into [vim-endoscope](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-endoscope).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a sketch of what you probably wanted. The builtin functions `searchpair` and `searchpairpos` are of enormous help for various text editing tasks :)

```
" Return a corresponding paren to be sent to the buffer
function! CloseParen()
    let parenpairs = {'(' : ')',
                   \  '[' : ']',
                   \  '{' : '}'}

    let [m_lnum, m_col] = searchpairpos('[[({]', '', '[\])}]', 'nbW')

    if (m_lnum != 0) && (m_col != 0)
        let c = getline(m_lnum)[m_col - 1]
        return parenpairs[c]
    endif
    return ''
endfun
```

To use it comfortably, make an `imap` of it:

```
imap <C-e> <C-r>=CloseParen()<CR>
```

**Edit**: over-escaped the search regexp so `\` got included in the search. One less problem now.

Comment: I have earlier written a similar solution to close LaTeX environments. It is a bit clumsier and more macro-esque than this. http://pastebin.com/Spu0e6bE

Comment: Works when there is something reasonable to do.  Barfs hardcore otherwise.  It'll get me started though, thanks!

Comment: @luqui: really? I tried out some no-op situations and it did the right thing to me.

Comment: @luqui: I see now. There is indeed something to be debuged.

Comment: @luqui: provided a fix. Please share if the script still barfs.

Comment: @progo: This is awesome. I've refined it a bit and posted it as a plugin [here](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-endoscope). Do you have any problem with me putting it up under [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)?

Answer (score 3):

Combined with the [autoclose](https://github.com/Lokaltog/AutoClose.git) plugin, you can set:

```
imap <c-l> <c-o>l
```

Autoclose will insert the matching bracket, then ctrl-L will skip over it without leaving insert mode.  Ctrl-L makes more sense to me than ctrl-].

This is as close as I can get to what I'd say you're asking for: "let me just press the same key every time to skip entering the correct bracket, no matter what that bracket is".  I'd not imap ] (without modifier) to this, but there's nothing stopping you if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that to your .vimrc and it will autoclose brackets

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
```

Comment: Yeah I always found that kind of annoying when editors did that.  Hard to tell what my context is or something...  thanks tho.

Comment: true, i have those commented out in my .vimrc :)